# how can I find the URL of an image from my library

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have a function with String parameter (URL) so I need to pass URL of an image. I didn't manage to do that from assets(I don't know why the path doesn't work correctly. I am using Adobe CC), so I would like to add an image to my library and pass the URL of that image. 
How can I do that?

I have tried this...but no results!

```
obj.setSound("assets/sound01.mp3");
```

`obj.setIcon("assets/plus.png");`

Comment: Try `URLRequest` , like: `obj.setSound(new URLRequest("assets/sound01.mp3"));
`

Comment: thank you for response. Unfortunately doesn't work...:( do you have any suggestion how to get url form my library image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load assets from library via code (actionScript), you must add class name for this element in library and call name like this:

```
var sound:Sound = new MyLibrarySound();
```

There MyLibrarySound special name, setting in properties for element

If you don't want to loaded some data, you can use Embed tag, to load some assets during compiling application:

```
[Embed(source="assets/sound01.mp3")]
var MyLibrarySound:Class;

var sound:Sound = new MyLibrarySound();
```

Comment: I was thinking about this, but the problem is the String parameter:-| The function is from an ANE file, so for that I need to make in this way...

Comment: If this is a iOS application, you must add asserts folder to you application, include them in ipa package, not to library in Flash IDE.

Comment: it is Android Application.

Comment: for android same instructions

Comment: I have assets in my apk, but the problem is I can't access files from that location. I don't know why...

Comment: If I use this :[Embed(source="assets/sound01.mp3")], I need to have sound01.mp3 into my library or into assets folder?

Comment: If you use Embed tag, assets must put near compiled data, not in the library. For library elements use new operator and set class-name in properties.